# What type of Unit measure do I obtain from a QGraphicView Class in its scene?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have located two points in my QGraphicsView which is map to my scene(QGraphicsScene).The two points are based on the mousecliked(mousePressEvent) made by the user, these points serve as the two endpoints of a line. I obtained the distance of the line using the formula to find the distance of two points. I am not sure what unit of measurement does I obtain, is it in pixel?

Comment: The scene has its own coordinates. And the mapFromScene methods serve to convert those coordinates to view coordinates.

Comment: @Elle It works just like the [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system): those are just *units*, they don't represent a specific measure; they could be pixels on your screen (if the view does not scale the scene) or those of an image, or even abstract units that represent other measurements like kilometers, seconds, liters or people. When you draw point `(1, 1)` in a Cartesian plane, that point will be 1 unit above and right of the center. Whether that distance would be 1 inch or a meter depends on how you define the scale of that unit.